# Can't download files from Google Drive using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been using a simple Google Apps Script code to download a file from my Google Drive to my local computer.

```
var dlUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + file.getId();

  // Open a dialog and run Javascript for downloading the file.
  var str = '<script>window.location.href="' + dlUrl + '"</script>';
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(str);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Downloading invoice ... please wait");

  // This is used for closing the dialog.
  Utilities.sleep(3000);
  file.setTrashed(true);
  var closeHtml = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<script>google.script.host.close()</script>");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(closeHtml, "Downloading invoice ... please wait");
```

This code has been working for over a year and then suddenly stopped working a few days ago with no changes to the code.  When I run it, I now get the message: "403.  That's an error.  We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. That's all we know."

I know the file exists and can be accessed because if I take the string in dlUrl and put it in the address bar of my browser, the file downloads without trouble.

I have also:

- Signed out of all other Google accounts, and have signed in only to the account that owns the file.
- Removed all saved passwords to the account
- Attempted to change the file permissions to universal EDIT permissions

While I do tinker with Google Apps Script, I consider myself a beginner still and would appreciate any suggestions on what I should try.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: For example, modifying `var str = '<script>window.location.href="' + dlUrl + '"</script>';` to `var str = '<script>window.open("' + dlUrl+ '", "_blank")</script>'` is the direction you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, that does work, once I enable pop-ups in my browser.  Thank you!  Just for my education, what is the difference between window.location.href and window.open and why does the latter not run into the access problem?

Comment: I think that `window.location.href` is the property of `window`. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) `window.open` is a method of `window`. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) `window.open` can use `_blank` while `window.location.href` cannot use it. Namely, `window.open` can open the URL as a new window. I thought that this might be the reason for this situation. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Your explanation was very useful.  Thank you for all your help!!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Although I searched the duplicated threads, I couldn't find it. So I post my comment as an answer because I thought that this your question and answer might be useful for other users who have ths same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var str = '<script>window.location.href="' + dlUrl + '"</script>';
```

#### To:

```
var str = '<script>window.open("' + dlUrl+ '", "_blank")</script>';
```

- `window.location.href` is the property of `window`. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) `window.open` is a method of `window`. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) `window.open` can use `_blank` while `window.location.href` cannot use it. Namely, `window.open` can open the URL as a new window. I thought that this might be the reason for this situation.
- And, when `_self` is used as the target of `window.open`, the same error with you like `403. That’s an error. We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. That’s all we know.` occurs. And, when `_top` and `_parent` are used, no download occurs. So I proposed to use `_blank`.

#### References:

- [Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)
- [Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem perfectly.

Comment: @Andrew Jeung Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: @Tanaike I had this problem too recently, but like Andrew Jeung i wonder how this could happen over just last month, when its worked before, is it google updating about GAS framework recently?

Comment: @Ztuons Ch About your question of `I had this problem too recently, but like Andrew Jeung i wonder how this could happen over just last month, when its worked before, is it google updating about GAS framework recently?`, I have to apologize for my poor skill. Unfortunately, I have no information about this. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: :)) You are very humble. thank you for all your useful snippet, i use it. thanks

Comment: @Ztuons Ch Thank you for replying. When I could obtain the information related to that, I would like to update my answer. But, now, I have to apologize.